# How to access a specific start_url in a Scrapy CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy, in particular Scrapy's `CrawlSpider` class to scrape web links which contain certain keywords. I have a pretty long `start_urls` list which gets its entries from a SQLite database which is connected to a Django project. I want to save the scraped web links in this database.

I have two Django models, one for the start urls such as `http://example.com` and one for the scraped web links such as `http://example.com/website1`, `http://example.com/website2` etc. All scraped web links are subsites of one of the start urls in the `start_urls` list.

The web links model has a many-to-one relation to the start url model, i.e. the web links model has a Foreignkey to the start urls model. In order to save my scraped web links properly to the database, I need to tell the `CrawlSpider`'s `parse_item()` method which start url the scraped web link belongs to. How can I do that? Scrapy's `DjangoItem` class does not help in this respect as I still have to define the used start url explicitly.

In other words, how can I pass the currently used start url to the `parse_item()` method, so that I can save it together with the appropriate scraped web links to the database? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you have the start_url field in the same table as the weblinks table(as in the DjangoItem you are using)? Sure, it will create redundant denormalization but if you want to avoid explicitly calling, this might help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default you can not access the original start url.

But you can override [`make_requests_from_url`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.make_requests_from_url) method and put the start url into a [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta). Then in a parse you can extract it from there (if you yield in that parse method subsequent requests, don't forget to forward that start url in them).

---

I haven't worked with `CrawlSpider` and maybe what Maxim suggests will work for you, but keep in mind that `response.url` has the url after possible redirections.

Here is an example of how i would do it, but it's just an example (taken from the scrapy tutorial) and was not tested:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),

        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse(self, response): # When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.
        for request_or_item in CrawlSpider.parse(self, response):
            if isinstance(request_or_item, Request):
                request_or_item = request_or_item.replace(meta = {'start_url': response.meta['start_url']})
            yield request_or_item

    def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
        """A method that receives a URL and returns a Request object (or a list of Request objects) to scrape. 
        This method is used to construct the initial requests in the start_requests() method, 
        and is typically used to convert urls to requests.
        """
        return Request(url, dont_filter=True, meta = {'start_url': url})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = Item()
        item['id'] = hxs.select('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
        item['name'] = hxs.select('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = hxs.select('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
        item['start_url'] = response.meta['start_url']
        return item
```

Ask if you have any questions. BTW, using PyDev's 'Go to definition' feature you can see scrapy sources and understand what parameters `Request`, `make_requests_from_url` and other classes and methods expect. Getting into the code helps and saves you time, though it might seem difficult at the beginning.

Comment: I think I roughly understand what you mean but I don't really know how to implement it. Can you perhaps provide a short example demonstrating how the `make_requests_from_url` method is usually used and how it relates to the `parse` method? I'm still a beginner. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks warwaruk, this works nicely. However, I found out that only the method `make_requests_from_url` and the configuration of the request's `meta` tag is necessary to get this working. I don't want to save the start url in the end, so it does not make sense for me to put it in an item. Anyway, thank you very much again! :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly the problem, You can get url from `response.url` and then write to `item['url']`.

In Spider: `item['url'] = response.url`

And in pipeline: `url = item['url']`.

Or put `response.url` into `meta` as warvariuc wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like warvariuc's answer requires a slight modification as of Scrapy 1.3.3: you need to override `_parse_response` instead of `parse`. Overriding `make_requests_from_url` is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Following Stephan Seyboth's advice, for Scrapy 2.5.0, I successfully over-rid `_parse_response` in the `CrawlSpider` class.  Check out [Scrapy's crawl.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py) for the current method definition that needs modification.  I also added the variable to meta, in `make_requests_from_url`.

```
def _parse_response(self, response, callback, cb_kwargs, follow=True):
    if callback:
        cb_res = callback(response, **cb_kwargs) or ()
        cb_res = self.process_results(response, cb_res)
        for request_or_item in iterate_spider_output(cb_res):
            yield request_or_item
    if follow and self._follow_links:
        for request_or_item in self._requests_to_follow(response):
            request_or_item.meta['start_url'] = response.meta['start_url']
            yield request_or_item

def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
    return Request(url, dont_filter=True, meta = {'start_url': url})
```

Then I can access `response.meta['start_url']` in the `parse_item` method.  This will contain the original start_url.

Comment: This worked for me. I overrode `start_requests` instead of `make_requests_from_url` as that method is deprecated.