# scrapy transport start_url to subsequent requests

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

since three days I am trying to save the respective start_urs in a meta attribute to pass it as item to subsequent requests in scrapy, so I can use the start_url to call a dictionary to populate my output with additional data. Actually it should be straightforward, because it is explained in the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) ...

There is a discussion in the google [scrapy group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de&fromgroups#!topic/scrapy-users/RSKnDgXnZE8) and there was a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598691/how-to-access-a-specific-start-url-in-a-scrapy-crawlspider) also but I can't get it to run :(

I am new to scrapy and I think it is a great framework, but for my project I have to know the start_urls of all requests and it is quite complicated as it looks like.

I would really appreciate some help!

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
class example(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'example'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/blablabla/', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for request_or_item in super(example, self).parse(response):
            if isinstance(request_or_item, Request):
                request_or_item = request_or_item.replace(meta = {'start_url':   response.meta['start_url']})
            yield request_or_item

    def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
         return Request(url, dont_filter=True, meta = {'start_url': url})


    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = testItem()
        print response.request.meta, response.url
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't study you question thoroughly enough. Sorry for a not quality answer. Now i see your code should have worked. I think you need to debug it, putting some prints. You can also study the `CrawlSpider` code in `scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider`. Or maybe someone else will have an answer for you, as i haven't really worked with crawl spiders, i prefer BaseSpider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to delete this answer as it doesn't solve OP's problem, but i thought to leave it as a scrapy example.

---

[Warning](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider):

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using `parse` as callback, since
>   the `CrawlSpider` uses the `parse` method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the `parse` method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

Use [BaseSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#basespider) instead:

```
class Spider(BaseSpider):

    name = "domain_spider"


    def start_requests(self):

        last_domain_id = 0
        chunk_size = 10
        cursor = settings.db.cursor()

        while True:
            cursor.execute("""
                    SELECT domain_id, domain_url  
                    FROM domains  
                    WHERE domain_id > %s AND scraping_started IS NULL  
                    LIMIT %s
                """, (last_domain_id, chunk_size))
            self.log('Requesting %s domains after %s' % (chunk_size, last_domain_id))
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            if not rows:
                self.log('No more domains to scrape.')
                break

            for domain_id, domain_url in rows:
                last_domain_id = domain_id
                request = self.make_requests_from_url(domain_url)
                item = items.Item()
                item['start_url'] = domain_url
                item['domain_id'] = domain_id
                item['domain'] = urlparse.urlparse(domain_url).hostname
                request.meta['item'] = item

                cursor.execute("""
                        UPDATE domains  
                        SET scraping_started = %s
                        WHERE domain_id = %s  
                    """, (datetime.now(), domain_id))

                yield request

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, I am quite new to scrapy and some concepts are still not that intuitive too me. It is great that you share your knowledge!

I now changed my code and implemented what you suggested, but I get the following error:

I am not quite sure what kind of db is referenced here, but I imported "from scrapy.conf import settings"

ERROR: Obtaining request from "/home/example.py", line 70, in start_requests
            cursor = settings.db.cursor()
        exceptions.AttributeError: 'CrawlerSettings' object has no attribute 'db'

Comment: Sorry, i posted a part from a real code. It takes start urls from a db. You can ignore the db parts, but i thought you would find them useful.

Comment: I see, I'll try to implement it over the weekend, thanks again!

Comment: @warvariuc thanks so much for pointing out the note about not overriding parse method, it was not obvious anywhere and was causing all the problem for me.